# find() problems

Tags: c++, search

I've got an error while using find() function. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

#define N 100000

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

    map<int,int> m;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) m[i]=i;

    find(m.begin(), m.end(), 5);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an compiller error:

```
error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first. __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, _Sequence>::operator* [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >, _Sequence = __gnu_debug_def::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > >]() == __val'
```

Including 'algorithm' nothing changes. Compiling in VS2008 shows similar error.

I know about m.find(), but I realy need to use find() too.

Thanks a lot for your assistance!

P.S. Actualy, the task is to compare speed of m.find(5) and find(m.begin(), m.end(), 5), so I need to make both of them work properly.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better test to compare with a simpler container, such as vector?

Comment: Can you say _why_ you need std::find instead of the member function? The member function is much faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`begin()` and `end()` on all STL containers provide access to elements of those collections. Type of those elements is known as `value_type` of the container. For `std::map<Key, Value>`, its `value_type` is `std::pair<Key, Value>`. Therefore, your `find` function is trying to find a `pair<int, int>` which is equal to 5. Since there's no `operator==` defined to compare `pair<int, int>` and `int`, you get the error.

The correct way to do this (so long as you want to avoid member `find()`) is to use `std::find_if`:

```
template <class First>
struct first_equal
{
   const First value;

   first_equal(const First& value)
        : value(value)
   {
   }

   template <class Second>
   bool operator() (const std::pair<First, Second>& pair) const
   {
        return pair.first == value;
   }
};

...

find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), first_equal<int>(5));
```

You could also overload `operator==` for `pair` and `int` to do what you want, but it's a very hackish way (because it will affect all your code, and because such a comparison has no meaning in general).

Answer (score 3):

find() requires a parameter that can be compared to *iterator. For your map, this will be pair<int,int>. You'll need to create a dummy pair, plus a comparison functor to compare the pairs.

Comment: `std::pair` is comparable so long as its elements are.

Comment: That's good to know. You usually don't know half of the pair you're searching for, so it's not generally useful, but in this case it just might be usable without a custom comparison functor.

Answer (score 2):

Just use m.find(5)

Comment: The question specifically asks to avoid the use of member `find()`